# How do I decode json array

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am using ajax to send data to a php page that queries mysql and returns the results. I have in my page, a variable that holds the dept value. However, if I var_dump($_POST) I see that the var is an array.

If I manually enter a value in the query, then data is returned. However, just not using my $dept var.

How do I decode this array to make the variable available for my query. Thanks

ajax code

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'deptdata.php',
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: {dept: depts},
   dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);

   },
      error: function (data) {

        alert('error');

        }
      });
```

post in firebug tab

```
dept=DEMOBILL
```

deptdata.php

```
<?php

    $dept = $_POST['dept']; <--- array?
    //open connection to mysql db
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sample") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "select custref from boxes where department = '".$dept."' and status = 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //create an array
    $emparray = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($emparray);

    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: You're open to mysql injection, look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: You don't appear to be sending any json and shouldn't need to. Not sure why you set `contentType` for it. Show how `depts` is defined

Comment: Only on local so no need for securty until it goes live

Comment: Try just removing the `contentType` and send back `$dept` to see if it is what you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myArray = json_decode($data, true);

echo $myArray[0]['id']; // Fetches the first ID
echo $myArray[0]['c_name']; // Fetches the first c_name
// ...
echo $myArray[2]['id']; // Fetches the third ID
// etc..
```

**If you do NOT pass true as the second parameter to json_decode it would instead return it as an object:**

```
echo $myArray[0]->id;
```

Comment: What is `$data`?

Comment: json data..!!   $data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data[0]["name"]; // "Rishii"


$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data[0]->name;  //"Rishii"

Comment: but there is no json in request payload shown in question

Comment: he encodeded into ... using  json_encode($emparray);  and Now Its Question How do I decode json array ..  Here is it. !!

Comment: That is for the response! Why would OP need to encode an array or object...then immediately decode it. That makes absolutely  no sense. Read the question. OP's immediate problem has nothing to do with response